# Horizontal bar in Android list activity

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

In my Android project, I want a horizontal bar in my list activity. How can I add this through layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can add headerView in your `ListView`.

Add a layout in the XML as header layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:paddingBottom="7dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
     <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/header_layout" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_gravity="center">

          <TextView 
              android:text="@string/header_text_1" 
              android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textSize="14dip" 
              android:textStyle="bold" 
              android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
          </TextView> 

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also in code:

```
View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null, false);
ListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Comment: yes, exactly. i want a horizontal bar, not header or footer view.

Comment: Shaireen: is it so, than what is R.layout.header_layout. please mention.

Comment: an indepndent widget for bar is not provided.It will be made using layouts.that is why R.layout.header_layout becoz it a layout in itself

Comment: Shaireen: would you pls provide me contents for header_layout

Comment: Shaireen: You got me wrong, actually i was looking for horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @romi: I got what was written in the question. U didnt use the word "scroll".

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you're looking for? 
http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx